# Requesting data from storage in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using Chrome storage API, which has method `chrome.storage.local.get('key');`

My program is going to store a list of data in each day.

What type of data I'm storing (Not so important)
`If user browse facebook.com for N minutes and google.com for M minutes in 2016/7/28, I'll store "facebook.com||N::google.com||M" in key "2016/7/28".
'::' seperates each data
'||' seperate domain and time.`

## What's the problem

The set of data may grow to a very large number, and one of my program feature will request uncertainly many (any natural number) date data from storage.
 **Considering:**
1. The number of days requested is uncertain, so the data shouldn't store in a single key. Or, I'll need to pull a huge amount of data from storage even if I only request for a single day, which seems absolutely idiot.
2. **BUT!** If the program request 100+ or much more data from storage, I'll need to call `chrome.storage.local.get('date');` method for each date. But I'm not sure how this method is implemented and whether it can complete such crazy task. Even if it could, I'm not sure whether should I chain the 100+ callbacks altogether (seems like a powerful bomb).
3. Or, should I give up this feature and force user to choose limited options (ex: can only choose 10, 50, 100, 365 days). In this case, I only need to manage data structure for each option. But this seems not cool :(

I would prefer case 1 or 2 than case 3. Or, is there any possible solution for this situation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`chrome.storage.local.get`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea) also accepts `array` as keys, you could wrap 100+ date as an array, say that is `[DAY1, DAY2, ..., DAY100]`,

```
chrome.storage.local.get([DAY1, DAY2, ..., DAY100], function (result) {
    var DAY1 = result.DAY1;
});
```

BTW, if the data is big enough, you would consider `unlimitedStorage` permission.

Comment: Thanks! You also pointed out a potential issue! I'll think about that!